# Elements inside position fixed disappears in internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have an element with position fixed. It wraps the browser height and has a width of 25% which sticks to the right. In IE, the elements inside it just disappear, but when I inspect the disappearing element, they appear and disappear again when I remove the focus from that element in the inspector. This is the CSS for the fixed element.

The rest of the content does not have any position absolute or fixed, which is overriding the .sidenavopen element.

```
.sidenavopen {
    height: 100%;
    width: 25%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9970;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2.5em rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.5);
    overflow-x: hidden; // transition: 0.5s;
    transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translatez(0);
    -ms-transform: translatez(0);
    -o-transform: translatez(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Doctype is also added in the main html file.

```
<!doctype html>
```

The first picture is IE, the second is in chrome.
[image: This is how it looks in IE]
This is how it looks in IE

[image: This is how it looks in chrome]

This is how it looks in chrome

Comment: Try to remove `translateZ`.

Comment: @KoshVery, another stackoverflow answer suggested to add that.

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: @KoshVery I didn't have it initially, I added it seeing that suggestion a while back. Made no difference.

Comment: If there is no difference, remove it definitely =))

Comment: Actually, could you please add a [mcve]? Snippet or jsfiddle, so people could see it in action?